# Native Android node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, web-hosting, stripe-connect

I'm developing a Ionic / nodeJS app that needs to have secret keys for Stripe and know that it's not good to store the keys inside the app due to it therefore being stored on the user's device.
My question is is there a way to host a NodeJs app somewhere else, but have the client side code "installed" on the user's phone through Cordova, ionic or others? What would the folder structure look like? Or what's the best way of tackling this?

- The Unique Secret API Key is the key that Stripe provides to me.

Comment: have you read the 'security' related docs w/ stripe API?  They may offer suggested net topology for native , mobile, clients to the api

Comment: I looked but haven't seen anything, besides for Android Java apps

Comment: hmmm. not a stripe api user. fwiw i looked over the outlines of the stripe android and it has CallBack that sets a token on the client which is pretty std for public apis. When u say "key" do u really mean the token value ( diff from a client side api key) in that server puts expiry to the token and server only provides token value to users with authenticated sessions. So, what exactly is the field and what exactly is the concern over security?

Comment: I mean key as in the Unique Secret API Key that Stripe provides to me. I've heard that if someone gets this key they can access stuff that they shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Usually you'd have a login on your `app` & store everything like that on the server. So say a user wanted to purchase something, you'd send a request to your backend and it'd validate your request (you'd use a token for this), it'd then find the stripe token and purchase the product.